# Splitting a random variable to give another random variable from the same family

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, geometric-distribution, conditional-distribution

Suppose you have a Poisson distributed random variable $N$ with expectation $\mu$.  You then take a conditionally binomially distributed random variable $X$ where $X \sim \textrm{Bin}(N,p)$ for some $0<p<1$.  It is well known that $X$'s marginal distribution is Poisson with expectation $\mu p$ and $N-X$ is also  Poisson but with expectation $\mu (1-p)$ and that $X$ and $N-X$ are independent.

There are more examples like this: for example if $N$ had a geometric distribution supported on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ with expectation $\mu$ (so with usual parameter $\frac{1}{1+\mu}$) and $X \sim \textrm{Bin}(N,p)$ then $X$'s marginal distribution is geometric with expectation $\mu p$ and $N-X$ is also  geometric but with expectation $\mu (1-p)$.  Here $X$ and $N-X$ are positively correlated. You can illustrate this with sampling with replacement from a bag with several red, light green, and dark green balls; stopping when you sample a red ball; and counting the number of green balls previously sampled for $N$ and the number of these which are dark green for $X$.

There are binomial distributions and negative-binomial distributions for $N$ which also show this splitting behaviour giving a marginal distribution for $X$ from the same family.

The behaviour of the expectations follows from the law of iterated expectation and is general, but staying in the same family of distributions is not.  Hypergeometric distributions do not seem to have this property, at least when they are not also Bernoulli.

My question is **whether there are many more well-known families of distributions with this binomial splitting property and whether there are necessary and sufficient conditions for a distribution to have this property**.

Comment: Possibly related and of interest. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.07276.pdf